# How to make my shader with GLSL

Tags: java, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to make a shader to a 3D game.

This is my shader codes :

main.frag

```
#version 330

out vec4 fragColor;
in vec4 color;

void main(void){
    fragColor = color;
}
```

main.vert

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 in_position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 in_color;

out vec4 color;

void main(void){
    color = in_color;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

But when i'm launching my game, i've got this error :

```
ERROR: 0:10: 'ftransform' : function is not available in current GLSL version 
ERROR: 0:10: 'ftransform' : no matching overloaded function found (using implicit conversion) 
ERROR: 0:10: 'assign' :  cannot convert from 'const float' to 'Position 4-component vector of float'
```

My graphic card's pilot is fully upgraded (a weak card). Have i to replace my "ftransform" function by an other ? If yes how ? If no, what can i do to replace it ? If i don't launch the shader, i don't have any color in my world.

Comment: Ftransform is an old function that has been removed in opengl 3. Try to search replace ftransform on Google, there are tons of info already.

Comment: Is this answer true ? : "Ftransform is equivalent to this:

v = ftransform();
v = gl_ProjectionMatrix * gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;

v will be a coordinate in projection (screen) space."

Comment: old matrix stack operations are no longer in gl 3, declare your matrices as uniform and compute the final transformation yourself

Comment: Thanks so much, do you know how i can do that ? I'm starting with this language. Thanks to your comprehension :-)

Comment: `gl_Position = projection_matrix * modelview_matrix * vec4(vertex, 1.0);` is the usual statemement, note the 4th component added to vertex to allow transformation of point with 4x4 matrices.

Comment: Ok but the program don't know the "projection_matrix", "modelview_matrix" and "vertex"'s value, true ?

Comment: Yes, you have to declare them yourself. You should look for a "modern opengl tutorial" otherwise this discussion will be endless :)